# Only return a record when all its associated records match the conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

We have :

```
class Campaign::Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign

  has_many :criteria
end

class Campaign::Item::Criterium < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign_item

  # This model has a +type+ field.
end

class Campaign::Item::Criterium::Gender < Campaign::Item::Criterium
  belongs_to :campaign_item

  # This model uses the a +gender+ field.
end

class Campaign::Item::Criterium::Age < Campaign::Item::Criterium
  belongs_to :campaign_item

  # This model uses the +age_min+ and +age_max+ fields.
end

class User
  # This model has a +gender+ and +birth_date+ field.
end
```

As you can see, users can create campaigns with items inside them.
Each campaign item can have many criteria based on gender and age.

Now we're trying to list all the campaign items that are matching the current user's information.

For example :
The current user is a `female` and has `25 years old`.
This user should be able to see an item that only has a `female Gender` criterium.
It should also be able to see an item that has a `female Gender` criterium and an `Age between 18 and 30 years old` criterium.
However, this user should not see an item that has a `female Gender` criterium and an `Age between 30 and 35 years old` criterium.

So the goal here is to return all the `Campaign::Item` where exactly *all* the criteria are matching the current user's information.
At the moment, we only managed to return `Campaign::Item` where *at least* one criterium is matching the current user's information.

Here some examples of queries we tried to achieve this goal :

```
SELECT "campaign_items".*
FROM "campaign_items"
INNER JOIN "campaign_item_criteria"
  ON "campaign_item_criteria"."campaign_item_id" = "campaign_items"."id"
WHERE
  ("campaign_item_criteria"."type" = 'Campaign::Item::Criterium::Gender'
   AND ("campaign_item_criteria"."gender" IS NULL
        OR "campaign_item_criteria"."gender" = 'female'))
  AND ("campaign_item_criteria"."type" = 'Campaign::Item::Criterium::Age'
       AND ("campaign_item_criteria"."age_min" IS NULL
            OR "campaign_item_criteria"."age_min" <= 17)
       AND ("campaign_item_criteria"."age_max" IS NULL
            OR "campaign_item_criteria"."age_max" >= 17))
```

This one doesn't work as it tries to find a criterium that has both `Campaign::Item::Criterium::Gender` and `Campaign::Item::Criterium::Age` types and obviously, this won't be the case any soon.

```
SELECT "campaign_items".*
FROM "campaign_items"
INNER JOIN "campaign_item_criteria"
  ON "campaign_item_criteria"."campaign_item_id" = "campaign_items"."id"
WHERE
CASE
  WHEN "campaign_item_criteria"."type" = 'Campaign::Item::Criterium::Gender'
       AND "campaign_item_criteria"."gender" = 'female'
       THEN 1
  WHEN "campaign_item_criteria"."type" = 'Campaign::Item::Criterium::Age'
       AND "campaign_item_criteria"."age_min" <= 17
       AND ("campaign_item_criteria"."age_max" IS NULL OR "campaign_item_criteria"."age_max" >= 17)
       THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END = 1
```

This ony also doesn't work as it returns the `Campaign::Item` as soon as *one* criterium matches the user's information, even if the other criteria aren't matching the user's information.

And now we're running out of ideas. Is there any chance we're gonna get such a behavior to work as expected in pure SQL ? Does anyone have any lead  ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `exists` in your where clause? (shorthand because f*** typing all that out again)

```
SELECT ci.*
FROM campaign_items ci
WHERE exists (select 1
              from campaign_item_criteria cic
              where cic.campaign_item_id = ci.id
              and cic.type = '::gender'
              and (cic.gender = 'female' or cic.gender is null)
             )
and exists (select 1
              from campaign_item_criteria cic
              where cic.campaign_item_id = ci.id
              and cic.type = '::age'
              and (cic.age = '35' or cic.age is null)
             )
```

Comment: What are your thoughts about INNER JOIN per criteria with complex ON clause?

Comment: `where exists` will stop as soon as it gets a positive result, `join` compares the whole table

Comment: @JohnHC Your solution works fine on items where all the existing criteria are given. However, if I remove the `Age` criterium, the user isn't matched anymore. A non-existing criterium implicitely means a 'matching' criterium.
BTW, didn't knew about the `EXISTS` expression, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a query that does exactly what I'm trying to do :

```
SELECT DISTINCT "campaign_items".*
FROM "campaign_items"
INNER JOIN "campaign_item_criteria"
  ON "campaign_item_criteria"."campaign_item_id" = "campaign_items"."id"
WHERE
  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM "campaign_item_criteria"
               WHERE "campaign_item_criteria"."campaign_item_id" = "campaign_items"."id"
                     AND "campaign_item_criteria"."type" = 'Campaign::Item::Criterium::Gender')
   OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM "campaign_item_criteria"
              WHERE "campaign_item_criteria"."campaign_item_id" = "campaign_items"."id"
                    AND "campaign_item_criteria"."type" = 'Campaign::Item::Criterium::Gender'
                    AND "campaign_item_criteria"."gender" = 'female'))
  AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM "campaign_item_criteria"
                   WHERE "campaign_item_criteria"."campaign_item_id" = "campaign_items"."id"
                         AND "campaign_item_criteria"."type" = 'Campaign::Item::Criterium::Age')
       OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM "campaign_item_criteria"
                  WHERE "campaign_item_criteria"."campaign_item_id" = "campaign_items"."id"
                        AND "campaign_item_criteria"."type" = 'Campaign::Item::Criterium::Age'
                        AND "campaign_item_criteria"."age_min" <= 17
                        AND ("campaign_item_criteria"."age_max" IS NULL
                             OR "campaign_item_criteria"."age_max" >= 17)))
```

So that's the query for 2 criteria and it has 4 subqueries. We already know we will end up with ~10 different criteria. So that's 20 subqueries total for the final request.
At the moment (with 2 criteria), it takes ~2.5ms with 2 `Campaign::Item` in the database and ~16ms with 2 000 `Campaign::Item` in the database. It's not as exponential as we thought it would be, so we'll say it 'good enough'.

We'll keep this one for now.
Does anybody have anything to add or any amelioration paths ?